# First time cruise. Arriving in port by plane hours before boarding. What do we do with our luggage?

Tags: usa, cruising, vacations

My wife and I are taking a trip with Carnival Cruise in October. We are traveling from Oklahoma to Louisiana by plane with a layover in Houston, TX. Our plan is to arrive early in New Orleans and go sight seeing for a bit before we board the ship.

We don't really want to haul our luggage around town. What are our options with dealing with our luggage while we are sight seeing? We've thought about renting a car, but I'm not sure if it would be worth it since we would have to return it before we boarded and possibly get a taxi to the port anyways.

The flight itinerary has us landing in New Orleans at 9:30AM and the cruise has arrival slots from 12:30am-3:00pm with departure set at 4:00pm.

Comment: Pardon for pinging here, I can‘t reach your Health.SE profile since you haven’t visited chat yet and don’t have any questions. [I‘ve created a chat room for the discussion regarding the question you posted on Health.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66559/room-for-narusan-and-mickb) Feel free to drop by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While pre-cruise touring is not generally recommended, luckily, this is quite feasible in New Orleans as the Port of New Orleans is just a couple of blocks from the French Quarter.

Barring unusual circumstances, you should be able to go directly to the Port from the airport and check your bags with the Porter at the pier.  Bag check begins well before check-in opens and embarkation begins and you likely won't arrive at the pier until 11am anyway.

For clarity, you check bags with the Porter before you check-in for the cruise.

You can pre-print the bag tags before you leave home.

Comment: "begins will before" should be "begins well before". Tried changing it but the stupid restriction is that edits must be at least 10 characters...

Answer (score 0):

[This service](http://www.advancecheckin.com) looks like exactly what you are looking for: they pick up the bags from the belt at the airport for you, and deliver them to the ship.